# Cocoa Touch best practice for capturing/logging/diagnosing crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash

As I get closer to releasing my first public iPhone app I'm concerned about catching crashes in the field. I'm curious to hear how others have gone about this.

I'm not sure what's possible outside of the debugger. Is all lost with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS or can I still catch it and get something useful into a log? Is the program main() the spot to put a @try/@catch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the kind of information I was looking for. I never found it with a search but saw it linked from another blog recently.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html

Answer (score 3):

Apple will collect all crashes for you, and if the user allows apple to gather the reports from his/her phone, you can see them inside iTunes Connect.

Comment: I assume this is the same crash report I get from the organizer. It's not very helpful. Is there anything I can capture that has more information?